# Найти первое вхождение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Почему выводит всю строку, если я указал, что надо только первый карман, с любыми цифрами, до первой не цифры?

```
echo preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '$1', '44f6&sor5t');
```

должно вывести **44**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php  Обратите внимание на 4й параметр функции - лимит замен. по умолчанию меняется все

Comment: не работает echo preg_replace('/(\d)+\1/', '$1', '44f6&sor5t', 1);

Comment: @Mike мне надо выполнить замену

Comment: @Mike вот так работает echo preg_replace('/(\d+).*/', '$1', '44f6&sor5t');, а что эта точка и звёздочка означает?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F  точка - любой символ, звездочка - 0 и более таких символов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preg_raplace() заменяет только те части строки, которые попали под выражение поиска. Все символы, которые под выражение не попали - остаются без изменений.

```
echo preg_replace('/(\d+).*/', '$1', '44f6&sor5t');
```

даст в результате `44`. Часть `.*` означает 0 и более любых символов, в итоге выражение можно прочитать как "Заменить *цифры*(то что в первых скобках) и идущие за ними любые символы на *цифры*".